# Custom login page for Windows Authentication when using IIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, asp.net-core, authorization

I am developing an intranet website application in ASP.NET Core 2.0 and trying to use Windows Authentication in conjunction with IIS, and then check the user against the authorised users in a database before the user can continue.

The issue is, that the default browser pop-up is not really what is desired. Ideally, I want to use a custom login/logout page with this method, but I don't think it's possible.

Alternative routes I have seen, are turning Windows Auth off, turning Anonymous auth on and using Cookies (but it seems the password is not checked against anything, only the username), or using Identity (which I suspect might be the best route).

What is the best route to follow in this situation? Are there any alternatives? Ideally, I would like to stick with Windows/AD auth in the current form and just provide a login page.

Thanks

Comment: Windows Authentication doesn't need a login page. The *browser* should be configured so it logins automatically. Even when that fails, authentication occurs on the *client* machine and no credentials are sent to the server.

Comment: In order to use your login form, you'd have to disable Windows authentication, create a normal login form  and use the credentials the user enters to authenticate against the domain/AD.