# ASP.Net core Windows Authentication unauthorized custom login page

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-authentication, iis-express

I have a requirement to implement this three login options to our website with ASP.Net Core_v3:

1. Automatic login when "windowsAuthentication" is true in **launchSettings.json** and user defined in domain.
2. Custom login with windows **Username** and **Password** when user is a local user and has a domain account
3. Custom login with **Username** and **Password** defined in our database when user is an anonymous user

the problem is when windows authentication is true, the browser login pop-up shows while I want to show our custom login page

I tried some solution to implement this but I did not succeed

**launchSettings.json:**

```cs
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": true
```

**Startup.cs:**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for 
        production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseActiveDirMiddleware();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

**401 unauthorized:**
[default browser pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpamb.png)

**LoginWithActiveDirectoryMiddleware.cs**

```cs
public class LoginWithActiveDirectoryMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly string _loginPath = "/Login/index";

    public LoginWithActiveDirectoryMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        bool isAthenticatedWithAD = IsAuthenticatedWithActiveDirectory(httpContext);

        bool isAllowedAnonymous = IsAllowedAnonymous(httpContext);

        if (!isAllowedAnonymous && !isAthenticatedWithAD)
        {
            httpContext.Response.Redirect(_loginPath);
        }

        return _next(httpContext);
    }

    private static bool IsAuthenticatedWithActiveDirectory(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        return (httpContext.User.Identity is WindowsIdentity winIdentity &&
                                            winIdentity.IsAuthenticated);
    }

    private static bool IsAllowedAnonymous(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var endpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
        var anonymousMethods = endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<IAllowAnonymous>();

        return anonymousMethods is object;
    }

}
public static class LoginWithActiveDirectoryMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseActiveDirMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<LoginWithActiveDirectoryMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

I'm forced to do it. please help me whether it's possible or not :) Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, when using Windows Authentication, it is impossible to use the custom login page, if you want to use the custom login page, you'd have to disable the windows authentication and use the form authentication. You could check the following threads: [Custom login page for Windows Authentication when using IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325221/) and [Possible Custom Login Page for Windows Authentication](https://forums.asp.net/t/2126118.aspx)

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT thank you for your helping. but I checked these two links before and I'm forcing to use Windows Authentication and Form Authentication at the same time. so that you say it's not possible.

Comment: Yes, I know you are using the Windows Authentication and Form Authentication at the same time, but in your description("when windows authentication is true, the browser login pop-up shows while I want to show our custom login page"), after researching I found above two links, it seems that when we using Windows Authentication, it is impossible to use the custom login page, we have to use the Browser popup window to login.So, I add a comment to explain it. Can you tell me which login page is used, browser popup or custom login page? About the 401 error, could you post the related login code.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT Sorry if my answer was confusing. I meant that your answer was correct and browser pop-up login form shows up when Windows Authentication is true. I tried some solutions to implement it but when Windows Authentication is true, server does not respond to client. I edit my code in the question and added a middleware just for completing my question and it's not working too (it's class name is LoginWithActiveDirectoryMiddleware.cs). [Active Directory Sample](https://github.com/MostafaNouri/ActiveDirectorySample) is my sample code.